# Clarification of what Ruby's 'require' does

Tags: ruby, rubygems

A heads up that I'm in no way a Ruby expert...I just use it from time to time for basic scripting. I'm trying to use the RubyCocoa framework so that I can use additional commands in my Ruby script.

As an example, if I was to try something as explicit as this:

```
#!/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby

require '/System/Library/Frameworks/RubyCocoa.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ruby/osx/cocoa.rb'

puts "Hello, World"
```

I receive this error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- osx/objc/cocoa.rb (LoadError)
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/RubyCocoa.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ruby/osx/cocoa.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from Test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

I do have Homebrew installed on my Mac (running 10.10), but why does the require command go through to the Cellar folder? You can see I'm trying to use the 2.0 Ruby version from my Frameworks folder (the one in /usr/bin is still 1.9.3 (would also love for someone to explain how these versions differ and why)).

Comment: How do you run your file? `./Test.rb` or `ruby Test.rb`? (I suspect the latter)

Comment: @Amadan I'm using an app called CodeRunner, which says it uses your latter format.

Comment: (Edited for own brainfart) Then `ruby` is your brewed Ruby. For the `#!` line to have any effect, you need to execute the file as a standalone executable. Or you need to explicitly state `/System/Library....../2.0/usr/bin/ruby Test.rb`.

Comment: I don't have rvm installed (yet). You're correct in that running from the command line with using `./Test.rb`, but now I get the same errors in my original question, just with the 2.0 Ruby paths instead.

Comment: Yeah, noticed about `rvm`, edited my response. Do you have RubyCocoa installed? Is it where you claim it is?

Comment: I believe it is installed correctly, it's just at `/System/Library/Frameworks/RubyCocoa.framework/...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63688/discussion-between-amadan-and-ricky).

Comment: The latest RubyCocoa framework on SoureForge says it "now supports Ruby 2.0", however the installer won't work on OS X 10.10.

Answer (score 2):

It goes through the Cellar folder because it is in your load path.
You can examine your load path by writing in your script

```
puts $:
```

#### Concerning your error message

You can use fully qualified path in `require` so

```
require '/System/Library/Frameworks/RubyCocoa.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ruby/osx/cocoa.rb'
```

is correct.

And indeed in your error message you can see this line

```
from /System/Library/Frameworks/RubyCocoa.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ruby/osx/cocoa.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
```

So you correctly `required` your file

However from the first line of your error message.

```
usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- osx/objc/cocoa.rb (LoadError)
```

We can see `ruby/osx/cocoa.rb` tries to require another file. This one is different and found under `osx/objc/cocoa.rb`. So those files have **similar names but are different**.

And since it tries to require with `require 'osx/objc/cocoa.rb'` it fails because it does not know how to find it (not a fully qualified path here).

Maybe you can try to change the load path variable.
By adding the line:

```
$: << '/System/Library/Frameworks/RubyCocoa.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ruby/osx/objc/'
```

It might work but I’m not sure since I don’t know where that osx/obj folder is located on your machine.

you might want to take some time to clean your ruby installation and maybe instead a fresh ruby using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) (I prefer rbenv)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately altering the load path doesn't help either (Amadan also tried this with me yesterday in chat). I think my version of RubyCocoa is not compatible with Ruby 2.0, and I can't update to the latest version of that because I am running on OS X 10.10. Just have to wait it out I guess.